# Regex match two characters following each other

Tags: python, regex

I have a string with several spaces followed by commas in a pandas column. These are how the strings are organized.

```
original_string = "okay, , , , humans"
```

I want to remove the spaces and the subsequent commas so that the string will be:

```
goodstring = "okay,humans"
```

But when I use this regex pattern: `[\s,]+` what I get is different. I get

`badstring = "okayhumans"`.

It removes the comma after okay but I want it to be like in goodstring.
How can I do that?

Comment: The `[ ]` means "any of", so  you're removing any `\s` and `,`. Try replacing with `(\s,)+`, if you dont want to capture that you can flag it: `(?:\s,)+`

Comment: `[\s,]+` is an *any combination* of spaces and commas, e.g. single comma `,` will be a match; that's why you should not *remove* matches, but *replace* them with `","`

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
[\s,]*,[\s,]*
```

With:

```
,
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/h79Aus/1)

---

- `[\s,]*` - 0+ leading whitespace-characters or comma;
- `,` - A literal comma (ensure we don't replace a single space);
- `[\s,]*` - 0+ trainling whitespace-characters or comma.

---

In Pandas, this would translate to something like:

```
df[<YourColumn>].str.replace('[\s,]*,[\s,]*', ',', regex=True)
```

Comment: this worked. thanks. I have now learned one more new thing about regex. @JvdV

Answer (score 1):

You have *two* issues with your code:

1. Since `[\s,]+` matches *any combination* of spaces and commas (e.g. single comma `,`) you should not *remove* the match but *replace* it with `','`
2. `[\s,]+` matches *any combination* of spaces and commas, e.g. just a space `' '`; it is not what we are looking for, we must be sure that at least one comma is present in the match.

**Code:**

```
text = 'okay, ,  ,,,, humans! A,B,C'

result = re.sub(r'\s*,[\s,]*', ',', text);
```

*Pattern:*

```
\s*    - zero or more (leading) whitespaces
,      - comma (we must be sure that we have at least one comma in a match)
[\s,]* - arbitrary combination of spaces and commas
```

Comment: Ah, the subtile difference with matching the 1st comma instead =). +

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
re.sub('[,\s+,]+',',',original_string)
```

you want to replace ",[space]," with ",".

Comment: That's not how character classes work if what you want to match is space delimited comma's. If your intention is to match any 1+ space/comma combination you can remove the 2nd comma in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use substitution:

```
import re

pattern = r'[\s,]+'
original_string = "okay, , , , humans"
re.sub(r'[\s,]+', ',', original_string)
```